# How to migrate a MySQL 8 database to MariaDB 10.5?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, upgrade

I want to migrate my MySQL 8 database to MariaDB 10.5

I exported my MySQL database to a ".sql" file.

I tried importing it with PhpMyAdmin to MariaDB :

[image]

My problem is that the import stops and I have errors :

[image]

Why is it not working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on linux you can make `sed -e 's/utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci/utf8mb4_unicode_ci/g' -i myfilename.sql`

As you see, you have to replace the collation through the complete sql file

Comment: So I replace `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` with `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ?